# Increment previous date time

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to display date time of previous date, The date time will be incremented according to actual time, This is done to display some data on previous date time which will be incremented according actual time, Please suggest any alternate method any.The below code gets duration of base time and will increment it according to current date time.

```
class Program
{
    private static double? Duration { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var startDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-02 11:17:55 AM");

        if (!Duration.HasValue)
            Duration = (DateTime.Now - startDate).TotalMinutes;

        for (var count = 0; count < 10000; count++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-Duration.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop simply doing `startDate.AddMilliseconds(100);`

Comment: It wont give you actual time.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question you might need something like this:

```
DateTime previous = DateTime.Now;

for (var count = 0; count < 10000; count++)
{
    Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - previous).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
    previous = DateTime.Now
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Basically you just need to store the current date now to be able to use it as previous date next time.

Comment: It still throws a Exception: `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`

Comment: This will change the previous date, You should keep the first value and increment according to time change.